# jQuery.html() function does not preserve values in selects and inputs in dynamic DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clone

I have content generated by PHP, but changed dynamically by jQuery. DOM is generated based on user's choises and I need all inputs, selects etc. be saved when user choose any option which re-generate DOM. For that I use `.html()` function. The problem is that only values, which were inserted by PHP are copied. Values which were set by `.val()` function or typed by user himself are lost when used `.html()`. I tried even `.clone()` function, but result is the same.

I have DOM similar to:

```
<div id="number_of_persons">
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="placeholder">
    <div id="person1">
        Name: <select><option value="">Name A</option><option value="">Name B</option></select>
        <div id="person1_placeholder">... another dynamically generated inputs ...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="person2">
        Name: <select><option value="">Name A</option><option value="">Name B</option></select>
        <div id="person2_placeholder">... another dynamically generated inputs ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When user change number of persons, for example from 2 to 3, I need first and second be saved (yes, the solution in this case would be use `.append()`, but the real DOM is quite complicated and whole `#placeholder` need to be regenarated). So I am using function simliar to:

```
$('#number_of_persons').on('change', function() {
    var html = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i += 1) {
        html += '<div id="person' + i + '">';
        html += 'Name: <select><option value="">Name A</option><option value="">Name B</option></select>';
        // the line below is the problem, because all selects and inputs lost their values set by user or via jQuery .val() function
        html += '<div id="person' + i + '_placeholder">' + ($('#person' + i + '_placeholder').html() || '') + '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    }
    $('#placeholder').html(html);
});
```

How to ensure copying values from selects and inputs in `#personX_placeholder`?

Comment: you are missing select names or id, then you can get each select value

Comment: Unfortunatelly, as I wrote, DOM in `#personX_placeholder` is quite complicated so I need to clone it whole. Beside that, it is generated dynamically so I don't even know how many elements there is.

Comment: In my case I am satisfied with https://api.jquery.com/html/, because I don't need to clone element as is, but only preserve values of inputs/selects of it, as described in commented line above.

Comment: By cloning I mean only preserve values of inputs/selects while refreshing DOM. I think that the code example is pretty clear what I need to do and what I do now. If I would use `.clone(true).html()` instead of `.html()` I use now (under commented line above), the result would be the same. So in this case I think it does not matter which function I use.

Comment: without method to access each inputs you cannot get or copy their values

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the you are implementing the for loop wrong, the `$('#id').html` does work but for loop that you trying to run in wrong.

To check remove `i <= $(this).val()` part in the loop, then just add `i<4` it will work fine.

Solution for your problem is to create an array of selection first,
in the `on(Chnage)` event push the element to the array like

```
selArry.push((this).val());
```

then use

```
    for(let x in selArry){
html += '<div id="person' + selArry[x] + '">';
        html += 'Name: <select><option value="">Name A</option><option value="">Name B</option></select>';
        // the line below is the problem, because all selects and inputs lost their values set by user or via jQuery .val() function .....
        html += '<div id="person' + selArry[x] + '_placeholder">' + ($('#person' + i + '_placeholder').html() || '') + '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    }
```

At last you can use,

```
$('#placeholder').html(html)
```

Comment: But the problem is with preserving values from inputs/selects which are in the `#personX_placeholder` element. These values I am trying to preserve with this method `$('#person_' + i + '_placeholder').html()`, but values are not copied.

Comment: the id wrong, `id="person2_placeholder"`  but you call `#person_+i+_placeholder`(it should be `#person+i+_placeholder`)

Comment: You're right, but it'is only typo in my example, I've fixed that already.